# How to Find another Integer that Sums up to Target number in the List in O(n)?

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose we have a list `A` that contains integers in it.

```
A = [2,4,5,6,7]
```

Then given a target integer t

`t = 6`

I'd like to find an index tuple of two elements which makes `t` by summing up.

```
return [0,1]
```

I had used my python and coded like below:

```
def myMethod(A,t):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(i,len(A)):
            if A[i] + A[j] == target:
                return([i,j])
```

This works, but some one told me there are better method only takes O(n) complexity on average.

How could it be possible?

Any hint?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done in *O(n)*. The trick is to keep an inverted index of where each number is in the list.

Once that is done, you can traverse the list and look if the difference between your requested sum and the current element is in the list, and if so where. Since `dict` uses hashes for lookup, this last step is done in *O(1)*.

```
def find_sum(s, lst):
    indices = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(lst)}

    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        target = s - x
        if target in indices:
            return (i, indices[target])

    return None

lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(find_sum(6, lst)) # (0, 1)
```

This solution could be adapted to return all such pairs by making `indices` store sets of indices instead of a single one.

Comment: if you nest your [if target in lst] in for loop, isn't it n^2?

Comment: @Beverlie sorry, I meant if target in indices

Comment: @oh, dict look up is just 1 right.

Comment: Yes, this solution only works for hashable objects for that reason. This can be made O(n log(n)) for objects which are comparable but non-hashable, but not any better